# Change label's value on form submit - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am brushing up on my rails. I have a dead simple form. views -> genalg -> index.html.erb

```
<h1>Genalg#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/genalg/index.html.erb</p>


  <%= form_with  url: "/calculate" do |form| %>  
  <%= form.text_field :query %>  
  <%= form.submit "calculate" %>
  <% end %>

<% unless @query.nil? %>
  <p><%=@query%></p>
<% end %>
```

I have a controller under controllers -> genalg_controller.rb

```
class GenalgController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @query = "biznass"
  end

  def calculate
    puts params
    @query = (params[:query].to_i * 2).to_s
    render :index
  end
end
```

In routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'genalg/index'
  post '/calculate', to: 'genalg#index' , as: 'index'
 
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

How, when I fill the from text :query and hit submit, can I get the text denoted at the very end of my view to display the value I put in times 2 (per the calculate function)? Seems like it should be easy but clearly I have forgotten some basic tenant of how forms and form submission works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the render to redirect_to and pass params like this

```html
  def calculate
    puts params
    @query = (params[:query].to_i * 2).to_s
    redirect_to index_path(query: @query)
  end
```

```html
<% unless params[:query].blank? %>
  <p><%=@query%></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your routes file, you are calling `index` action on submitting a post request for `calculate` so its always returns @query value from the index method i.e. `biznass`

If you want to calculate @query using params and use index action for that with same routes defined, you have to update index method

```
def index
  if params[:query]
    puts params
    @query = (params[:query].to_i * 2).to_s 
  else
   @query = 'biznass'
  end
```

OR you can change route and controller code

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'genalg/index'
  post 'genalg/calculate'
 
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

```
class GenalgController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @query = params[:query] || "biznass"
  end

  def calculate
    puts params
    @query = (params[:query].to_i * 2).to_s
    redirect_to index_path(query: @query)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use `resources` in your routes.rb instead doing it like that, it will be far more concise, scaleable and you can use url helper method. you can run `rake routes` in your terminal to see detail of routes, like helper method's name, path, http verb, and which controller's method a path is using.

```
resources :genalg, controller: :genalg, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    post :calculate
  end
end
```

in this instance of `def calculate`, If you have method with http verb `POST` and it supposed to response with success status, most of the time you need to redirect it instead of rendering it, because in case when user refresh or copy url after `calculate`, the page will not be found as `calculate` have `POST` http verb.
so you have to change `render` to `redirect_to` and pass params `:query`, so every time user refresh the page after calculate, `:query` will be persisted. even if you want to store `:query` in database this is still applicable. also, in here you can see we use helper method to redirect to index page by using `genalg_index_path`

```
def calculate
  puts params
  query = (params[:query].to_i * 2).to_s
  redirect_to genalg_index_path(query: query)
end
```

then in index you can check whether params query is empty or not

```
def index
  @query = params[:query] || 'biznass'
end
```

And in view as you can see we use helper method again to get calculate path, and we don't need `@query` condition as it never `nil`

```
<h1>Genalg#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/genalg/index.html.erb</p>

<%= form_with url: genalg_calculate_path do |form| %>  
  <%= form.text_field :query %>  
  <%= form.submit 'calculate' %>
<% end %>

<p><%=@query%></p>
```